# Regexp: |(OR) condition doesn't work

Tags: php, regex

Can't figure out why OR condition in my regexp isn't working.

```
    $str = "                            <li><a href=\"\" class=\"gateway-image\"><img src=\"<?=theme_url()?>/images/Cherry Credits.jpg\" alt=\"\"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href=\"\" class=\"gateway-image\"><img src=\"<?=theme_url()?>/images/gudangvoucher.jpeg\" alt=\"\" style=\"width: 140px!important\"/></a></li>";

    $regexp = '/^(.*\<li\>\<a href\=)(.*cherry|credits.*)$/im';
    preg_match($regexp, $str, $m);
```

It seems regexp is correct but it can't find string `Cherry Credits.jpg` as I expected. What is wrong?

Comment: Your expression expects either `cherry` at the end of the line, or `credits` right after `href=`. Thus, no match is returned.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but there is .* at the end

Comment: Even if there is `.*`, there is no "cherry" right after "href=". What is the rule for extraction? Get all "a" "href" values containing "cherry" or "credits"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've written the expression using the start- and end-of-line anchors `^` and `$`.

This doesn't match because your string continues on after `cherry` *and* there are additional characters between `href=` and `credits`.

You can either remove the line anchors:

```
(.*\<li\>\<a href\=)(.*cherry|credits.*)
```

Or you can move the trailing `.*` (and probably the leading `.*`) outside of the capture group:

```
^(.*\<li\>\<a href\=).*(cherry|credits).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "$" sign at the end, because it will expect a end of line.

Try this:

`^(.*\<li\>\<a href\=).*(cherry|credits)(\.jpg)`

You can use online testers like this site: https://regex101.com/ and check if you are doing OK.